# mySQL need timezone displayed in EST but cannot change global time settings

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I am facing an odd issue. The global timezone setting in the mySQL is in UTC. There are multiple tables (sub databases) within a single instance of mySQL (I am using database.NET as the manager); so I can't change the global timezone.

The following is my query. *All I need is to display the times in EST*. I have seen a few solutions with `@@sessionTimeZone` but they didn't work. **Furthermore, I am running into the issue of data being collected till 9PM EST, but in UTC that's 1AM on the next day**.

My main confusion is that the data is already stored in the table in UTC; however, I would like to see those `datetime` fields displayed in EST.

`cartId` is a numerical field
`createDate` is a datetime field

I am just using http://fishcodelib.com/database.htm and connecting to the mySQL database.

```
SELECT   DATE(createDate)
    ,DATE_FORMAT(createDate, '%l%p') as HourOfDay
    ,count(cartId) as numCarts_ALL

FROM carts
WHERE createDate >= '2014-09-24' 
      AND createDate < '2014-10-01'
      AND HOUR(createDate) >= 10 AND HOUR(createDate) <21   
GROUP by DATE(createDate),HOUR(createDate)
;
```

I will really appreciate any help.
Thanks again

Comment: What datatype is your `createDate` column? Is it `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, or maybe something else? Also, what host language are you using for your app? Is it C# (.net)?

Comment: Excellent questions. Please see edits

Comment: @OllieJones: another related question is: in the `where` clause that filters out the data by the hour of the day, is there a way to say, get all the data from 4pm today till 2am tomorrow? Essentially, `HOUR(createDate +1) <3`?

Answer (score 2):

`DATETIME` data types are not affected by either the global or connection-local timezone setting. That only works for `TIMESTAMP` data types. That explains why your attempts to muck around with @@session.TimeZone don't have any effect. `NOW()` and `CURDATE()` *are* affected, though.

You say your `DATETIME` data is stored in UTC. That's excellent. Life is *much* easier when you store your data that way.

Before you use the advice I'm about to give you, please make sure your MySQL server has its timezone tables loaded correctly.  Do this command and make sure you don't get a NULL result.

```
 SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'America/New_York', 'UTC')
```

If this doesn't work -- if you get a `NULL` or an error -- you need to get your server people to load the time zone tables. They should do this. They know how. (If they don't, you should get a new service provider.)

We need to use the timezone named 'America/New_York' because presumably you want to switch automatically between EDT and EST on the appropriate dates each year.

Now, to retrieve a correctly converted UTC `DATETIME` value from a table, you do this:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(createDate, 'UTC', 'America/New_York') AS createDate
  FROM yourTable
```

This is cool because you can make the timezone setting a user preference if you have users in various time zones.

To store a local time value as UTC just do it in reverse.  For example.

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (createDate) VALUES (CONVERT_TZ(?, 'America/New_York', 'UTC'))
```

Now do

```
SELECT NOW()
```

and look to see whether NOW() is in local time or in UTC.  If it is in UTC, then you should start your session by doing `SET TIME_ZONE='America/New_York'` . This will get your timezone set right so `NOW()` and `CURDATE()` do what you want.

Then, to fetch yesterday's (local time) rows from your table do this:

```
WHERE createDate >= CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(),'America/New_York','UTC') - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND createDate <  CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(),'America/New_York','UTC')
```

This will convert midnight local time to UTC and fetch the range of items.

To get all the data from 4pm today until 2am tomorrow, you could do this:

4pm today (localtime) is  `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 16 HOUR` . 2am tomorrow is  `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 26 HOUR` or you could write it `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 2 HOUR`

So fetching that range would need this:

```
WHERE createDate >= CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 16 HOUR,'America/New_York','UTC')
  AND createDate <  CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 26 HOUR,'America/New_York','UTC')
```

You could also use `ADDTIME(CURDATE(),'16:00')` to obtain a `DATETIME` value for 4pm today, if you'd rather combine ordinary date objects and ordinary time objects. Similarly, you could get 2am tomorrow like this:

```
  ADDTIME(CURDATE(),'02:00') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Notice that this form of WHERE clause allows a [range scan on an index](http://www.percona.com/blog/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes/) on the `createDate` column. This is very good for performance.

Comment: this is such a great explanation! Thank you so much. I did get a `NULL` result when executing the initial query `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'America/New_York', 'UTC')`; so I have reached out to the server guys; waiting to hear back.

Just curious: had your solution to be adjusted to get data from 8pm ET to 2am ET across multiple dates, how will you change the solution? Also, you mentioned about "WHERE clause allows a range scan on an index"-- what is a range scan on an index?

Once I get a handle on this, I will try it out; if it works, I will definitely update you! Thanks again!

Comment: See my updates. I added a link to an explanation of range scans.

Comment: I would not mess around with timezone setting, this might lead to inconsisenties. If most date(time)s are already stored in UTC keep doing that.

Answer (score 0):

To convert datetime from a timezone to another timezone:

```
SELECT DATE(CONVERT_TZ(createDate, '+00:00', '-04:00')) createdDate,
       HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(createDate, '+00:00', '-04:00')) hourOfDay
FROM carts
WHERE
    createDate BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 16 HOUR AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 26 HOUR
GROUP BY createdDate, hourOfDay
```

For different dates

```
SELECT DATE(CONVERT_TZ(createDate, '+00:00', '-04:00')) createdDate,
       HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(createDate, '+00:00', '-04:00')) hourOfDay
FROM carts
WHERE
    createDate BETWEEN '2014-09-24' AND '2014-10-01'
GROUP BY createdDate, hourOfDay
    HAVING hourOfDay <= 2 OR hourOfDay >= 20
```

You might think "why not in WHERE clause?"

If functions are used in the where clause, indexes can't be used (which results in a full table scan). So just filter out the records within the daterange, and the hours in the HAVING clause

FYI

```
CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 16 HOUR
```

Is short for

```
DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 16 HOUR)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made a quick edit to the initial query; I am trying to gather data between, say 8PM and 2AM across different dates. Is there a way to morph this to meet that need?

Also, can you explain the how the `interval 16 HOUR and 26 HOUR` are doing the job?

Comment: See the editted answer, note that hourOfDay is converted to EST timezone

Comment: I see. I think the having clause should be `HAVING hourOfDay >= 20 AND hourOfDay <3` to get data from 8pm to 2am (say 8pm Sep 29 to 2am Sep 30)? Just curious how the OR is serving that purpose.

Comment: A number can not be bigger then 20 and smaller then 3 at the same time, hence the OR ;-) Note that if you have input in your local timezone you need to convert it back to UTC

Comment: Another thing is, I am trying to display the hour of the day as in AM/PM. Earlier, I had the following `DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(createDate,'+00:00','-04:00'), '%l%p') as HourOfDay`; however, inserting this line into the code given instead of the `HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(createDate, '+00:00', '-04:00')) hourOfDay` does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: Dangit! Sheesh, sorry about that. Didn't realize what I was implying. Using your code, there is another issue with the `HAVING` clause that I am running into. I am trying to see data from 9AM to 9PM ET (note that 9PM ET is 1AM UTC on the next day). I adjusted the `HAVING` clause as `HAVING HourOfDay >= 9 AND HourOfDay <22`; what happened is that I was seeing data from the previous day pop up (the ones that ran over the UTC 24hr point)--to solve this, I added `AND createdDate >= current_date`. For some reason, I don't see any data anymore. Any idea why?